# how to enable opening of the input terminal wndow in gvim when running the program after compilation just as it appears in codeblocks or geany?

Tags: ubuntu, vim, terminal

I am currently working on ubuntu 19.04 and I have recently started using GVIM but it does not open the input terminal when I compile and run the code, instead I need to go into the terminal manually and then execute the program from within that terminal manually. Can someone provide solution as to how I can allow GVIM to open the input terminal window by itself whenever I run the program. Any help would be greatly appreciated. (I mostly execute only C++ programs so if you could provide solution to do that even for like a single language then that would be like really helpful).

Comment: Read `:h terminal`

Comment: Could you plz be more specific, I read it but could not find the solution

Comment: What's unclear in typing in `:term ./myprog` (or maybe `:!./myprog` for a non-interactive application)? I just don't get your question.

Comment: to explain the question clearly, like when you work on some ide like codeblocks, intellij, pycharm etc. you can just press a key and the new window opens where you can put the input text and get the output, I want the same functionality in gvim. Is it possible?

Comment: I want my gvim to function in the same way as this guy's. LINK --> https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=oY0PBQt36YM

Comment: Read `:h key-mapping` then.